# Map induced in homology by a product of maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let us take two continuous maps $\phi : X \rightarrow Y$, $\psi : W \rightarrow Z$ between topological spaces and let us consider the induced homology map on the product: $H_n(\phi \times \psi)$. I am trying to understand the behavior of this map. Here's what I think:

> In a completely general setting we don't know how this map behaves but if we suppose that the maps
>   $$
> \begin{array}{c}
> \displaystyle{\bigoplus_{p+q=n} H_p(X,A) \otimes H_q(W,A) \rightarrow H_n(X \times W, A)}\\
> \displaystyle{\bigoplus_{p+q=n} H_p(Y,A) \otimes H_q(Z,A) \rightarrow H_n(Y \times Z, A)}
> \end{array}$$
>   are isomorphism then:
>   $$
> H_n(\phi \times \psi) = \bigoplus_{p+q=n} H_p(\phi) \otimes H_q(\psi)
> $$

Unfortunately I'm not able neither to give a counterexample when one of the maps isn't an isomorphism nor to prove my claim when both the maps are isomorphism. Mainly my problem is that I don't understand how to interpret the maps $H_p(\phi), H_q(\psi)$ when I'm working with the cellular complex, which is what I have to do when dealing with the Kunneth's morphism.

Thank you!

Comment: If $A$ is a PID (I think spectral sequences become involved otherwise), the Kunneth theorem gives an exact sequence:
$$
0\to\bigoplus_{p+q=n}H_p(X;A)\otimes H_q(W;A)\to H_n(X\times W;A)\to\bigoplus_{p+q=n-1}\mathrm{Tor}_A(H_p(X;A),H_q(W,A))\to 0
$$
so for your question about finding a counterexample, you should look to make one of the $\mathrm{Tor}_A(H_p(X;A),H_q(W,A))$ terms nontrivial.

Comment: The Kunneth map is induced by the cross product $C_p(X) \otimes C_q(Y) \to C_{p+q}(X \times Y)$, which is natural in $X, Y$. So I believe the answer is yes, but I haven't thought much about it.